# Batch file to create folders and subfolders and copy files into them

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

I need to copy any pdf files with the word "approved" in the file name from here:

C:\Projects\Project_1\

C:\Projects\Project_2\

To here:

C:\Attachments\Project_1\Documents\

C:\Attachments\Project_2\Documents\

The batch file needs to create the project folder as well as 2 subfolders, "Documents" and "Images" and put the corresponding pdf files in the "Documents" folder.

I created a simple batch file using xcopy but I cannot figure out a way to put the pdfs into a subfolder.

xcopy "C:\Projects\Project_1*approved*" "C:\Attachments\" /s /d /y

Comment: Why don't you specify the full path to the subfolder as the second argument to xcopy?

Comment: If you are already doing it for each project, you can put that folder into the xcopy line like: xcopy "C:\Projects\Project_1*approved*" "C:\Attachments\Project_1\" /s /d /y

Comment: There are multiple project folders, e.g. Project_1, Project_2, Project_3, etc. The batch file needs to create these folders along with the subfolders.  The original project folders do not have subfolders.